# how to decompress with pigz

Tags: compression, tar, gunzip

I am trying to use pigz for parallel compress and decompress. I have found a way to compress in parallel using the following command:

```sh
tar cf - /input/dir | pigz > output_file.tar.gz
```

What is the equivalent command to decompress? I need to be able to specify the filename and the output directory path in the command for it to be useful for me.

Comment: http://zlib.net/pigz/pigz.pdf

Comment: You can't decompress in parallel, though.

Comment: _pigz_ stands for _p_ arallel _i_ mplementation of _gz_ ip, and is an anagram of gzip.  It is pronounced pig-zee.

Comment: This question does not belong in stackoverflow.

Comment: pigz -d < test.tar.gz | tar xf - -C /this/directory

Comment: @MarkAdler: It's going to be pronounced "pigs", regardless of what a couple of geeks want to throw up on a web page.  They are not above the rules of phonics.  (They could have been, if they'd capitalized or something.  But if they want to make it look like a word, it's gonna get pronounced like one.)  And really?  Anagrams are a thing, that people actually do?  I hadn't seen a live person do it before; hell, i'm still about 80% convinced it's just some BS they made up for detective shows.  :)

Comment: @cHao - I'm pretty sure when the author tells you how something's pronounced, you take his word for it.

Comment: @atxdba: Tell that to the guys who invented GIF.  They have told people how it's pronounced, and everyone i've talked to openly disregards it.

Comment: @cHao why should you not be possible to decompress in parallel? Comparing `gunzip -c disk_image.gz | ...` and `pigz -dc disk_image.gz | ...`, `pigz` runs about 3x faster.

Comment: @Cadoiz: Because pigz didn't have an option for it at the time of writing.  As for why it wasn't an option at the time, gzip relies on previous contents to build the table to (de)compress future contents. You need to process what came before to understand what comes after. Which makes the process of decompression inherently serial. That changes if you can find boundaries between chunks, but that's nowhere near as simple for decompression as for compression.

Comment: @Cadoiz: Now, there are parts that can be done while the decompression is going on (reading the next bit of data, writing out results, etc), and doing those on another thread can speed things up if the decompression takes longer than the I/O.  If it doesn't, though, you're I/O bound, and past a certain point, parallelization can actually slow you down a bit.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use `pigz -dc` for decompression to stdout.  Then use `>` as you are in your example to direct the output to the desired path and file.

You can type just `pigz` for command options help.

Answer (score 22):

You're probably looking for something along the lines of:

```
pigz -dc archive.tar.gz | tar xf -
```

but noting Mark Adler's (legendary, at this point) original post, pigz does not utilize multiple cores for decompression. However, it does utilize additional cores for reading, writing, and some additional calculations, which do yield a moderate performance increase over gzip. Enjoy!

Answer (score 10):

`tar -I pigz -xvf compressed_file.tar.gz`

Comment: Just curious, can I still use `tar -xzvf compressed_file.tar.gz` to extract an archive that is compressed by pigz?

Comment: Absolutely panc, pigz is just a multi-threaded gzip compressor/decompressor, the format is the same.

Comment: Worked great, also worked for .tar as well not just tar.gz.

Answer (score 8):

For some reason, pigz doesn't autocomplete ".gz" compressed files, but if you type the names of your files pigz finds them.

To decompress and keep your compressed files use: `pigz -dk yourfilename.gz`.
If you don't need the compressed versions use just `pigz -d yourfilename.gz`.

`pigz --help` shows all the options available.

Comment: So the presence of `-k` determines if the archive `yourfilename.gz` is kept or not? Or what does it do?

Comment: man pigz|grep -A1 -- '-k'
      `-k --keep`
              `Do not delete original file after processing.`